# Where to build and deploy Microsoft Graph email program into sandpit environment?

Tags: azure, email, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to build a test application sending out emails in  a sandpit environment?

I've built a simple app to send out emails (using Microsoft Graph) but when I tried to publish it in Microsoft Azure I get a bunch of issues.

The screenshot is grainy but the error message on the top right is "*

> Verify MPN ID" The MPN ID you provided (XXX) does not exist, or you do
> not have access to it. Please provide a valid MPN ID and try again

*.

When I log into MPN it has not passed my business verification checks. Speaking to MPN they asked for a business registration document, which I do not have and have no intention of paying ($500-600) to build a sandpit environment just for proof of concept (POC).

The yellow box under Publisher verification says this "

> Starting November 9th, 2020 end users will no longer be able to grant
> consent to newly registered multitenant apps without verified
> publishers.

"

So my question is, is there a way to build a test email program (Azure/MS Graph) sending out to people outside my organisation in a sandpit environment (existing organisation account is blocked to prevent access to production)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you would like a test tenant on which you would like to call Graph Api from your POC App.

While there exists Microsoft 365 program and you can utilize this for the right graph query. You can add test users, sharepoint site and more . You can avail this at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoft-365/dev-program

Once you sign up, you can login to Graph Explorer and try it.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

This can be utilized for 92 days.

That said, to call a Graph API you will need another test tenant to try it on, nothing readily available.