# How to automate email testing for applications built using Azure Graph

Tags: typescript, email, ui-automation, azure-ad-graph-api, playwright

I would like to automate the email testing for application that is built using Azure Graph.
I am using playwright with typescript for the rest of the testing.
My application sends an email and I want to check if the user has received the email. How to get details such as smtp for these applications and also please suggest some tools that can be used for this testing

Answer (score 0):

> How to get details such as smtp for these applications and also please
> suggest some tools that can be used for this testing

To achieve the above requirement,

> For sending an email from Azure VMs or Azure App Service, you need
> authorized `SMTP relay services`. (`These relay services normally connect via TCP port 587, although they accept connections from other ports as well`.) These services are used to maintain IP and domain
> reputation in order to reduce the chances of external domains
> rejecting or putting your messages in the SPAM bin.
>
> There is One such SMTP tool provider is [***SendGrid***](https://sendgrid.com/partners/azure/), although
> there are others.

*For complete setup please refer this* **Blog**|[***Sending e-mails with Microsoft Graph using .NET***](https://zimmergren.net/sending-e-mails-using-microsoft-graph-using-dotnet/) & this [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66574631/where-to-build-and-deploy-microsoft-graph-email-program-into-sandpit-environment)

Answer (score 0):

To check if an email have been correctly sent by your application in a Playwright E2E test, you can use an external service like [TestSendr](https://testsendr.link).

This (free) service will allow you to send an email to something ending by **@testsendr.link**, and then check the email received via a simple REST API. Check the [quick start](https://testsendr.link/docs/quick-start)!

Answer (score 0):

If you want an SMTP server for testing that doesn't actually deliver emails to the recipient, then I recommend trying out https://mailsnag.com. You can have multiple mailboxes and see all the emails received for each mailbox.